# How can I convert @helper function to a partial view I call?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this @helper function in a Helpers.cshtml file located under ~/App_Code:

```
@helper TempCost(Decimal cost)
{
@: @String.Format("{0:C0}", cost)
}
```

That I would have used thusly in my view:

```
@Helpers.TempCost(Model.PriceInformation.MyPrice)
```

`PriceInfrormation` is my model, and `MyPrice` is a property within (decimal).

I now want to put this helper in it's own partial view. I can call the partial view and pass the arguments with no problem. However, I do not know how to get the code in the partial view to work.

I tried something like:

```
@{
decimal cost;
}
@String.Format("{0:C0}", cost)
```

but am getting the following error:

> error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'cost'

Sorry, not a programmer by profession. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

In the user control

```
@model decimal
@string.Format("{0:C0}", Model)
```

And call

```
@Html.Partial("yourusercontrol", Model.PriceInformation.MyPrice)
```

Comment: This works in a regular MVC project. Thanks. Now I am trying to get it to work in an Orchard module and am getting an error using @model because it's expecting an IShapeProxy. Any thoughts on how to do this with out model and keeping the use of cost?

Comment: I am sorry. I've no idea about Orchard. You could add appropriate tag to your question for getting response from others.

Comment: Well that worked in my scenario, Orchard would have been a bonus. Thanks.